# How to make an R function to turn a vector into a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am just learning R and got to functions. I have made a function of 0 or more variables, but they always return one value. I can make a function that returns a vector of values using `c(x,y,z)`, but when I input a vector, it just returns a longer vector. For example if I make a function `f <- function(x) { c(x, x^2, x^3) }` and pass it `2`, it returns `2, 4, 8`. But if i pass it the vector `2,3,4`, it returns `2,4,8,3,9,27,4,16,64`. Where I would like a matrix with 3 rows corresponding to the 3 inputs I gave it, and 3 columns with the return values. So a 3x3 matrix with the columns `(2,3,4),(4,9,16),(8,27,64)`. I would also love to be able to do this using base functionality, although if I have to use a package to do this that would also be fine

tried input `(2,3,4)`. wanted output:

```
2   4   8
3   9  27
4  16  64
```

but got `(2,4,8,3,9,27,4,16,64)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `matrix()`, with `nrow` set to the length of the input vector:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  matrix(c(x, x^2, x^3), nrow = length(x))
} 

f(c(2, 3, 4))

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    4    8
#> [2,]    3    9   27
#> [3,]    4   16   64
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: There is already a function in R that does this. ie `poly(c(2,3,4), k = 3, raw = TRUE)` should give you back the matrix you want

Answer (score 2):

I think `cbind` is all you need here:

```r
f <- function(x)  cbind(x, x^2, x^3) 

f(c(2, 3, 4))
#>      x      
#> [1,] 2  4  8
#> [2,] 3  9 27
#> [3,] 4 16 64
```

However, any solution involving a single call to `matrix` or `cbind` with an atomic value of x (such as `f(2)`) will produce a single-row matrix rather than a vector. If you want a vector rather than a matrix in this situation, you can do

```r
f <- function(x)  (if(length(x) == 1) c else cbind)(x, x^2, x^3) 

f(c(2, 3, 4))
#>      x      
#> [1,] 2  4  8
#> [2,] 3  9 27
#> [3,] 4 16 64

f(2)
#> [1] 2 4 8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this has also worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer()` to make the function scale to accept an arbitrary length vector.

```r
f <- function(x) {
  y <- seq_along(x)
  outer(x, y, "^")
} 

x <- 2:4

f(x)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    4    8
#> [2,]    3    9   27
#> [3,]    4   16   64
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another answer with `outer()`. You can provide one vector of bases and one of exponents:

```r
f <- function(x,y) x^y

outer(
    c(2,3,4),
    c(1,2,3), 
    f
)
```

Output:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    4    8
# [2,]    3    9   27
# [3,]    4   16   64
```

This also produces the desired output if the vectors are not of the same length.